# RHEL- Limited root access

Tags: linux, rhel

I need to allow certain users limited access to the lab server. The server is RHEL 5.6.  However, I don't want to give them the root access. Basically, we have configured a LDAP server where all the users have centralized NFS and LDAP login from any of the client machines in the network. So, the LDAP users home area is located in /home/users in the server. I need to give access to only this folder to a certain user.

If I edit the visudo file and add the following line in the RHEL server, will I be able to accomplish what am looking for?

```
user1, %operator ALL= /home/users
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are authenicating users with ldap and nfs mounted share, as such users of ldap or without ldap would be restricted to work in their home directory only.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: Yeah. I want to give access to a non LDAP user only in the server.

Answer (score -2):

Basically, as you giving all users access as users not as root hence all users will not have root access either using local authentication or remote authentication. I hope the users don't know your root password. :)

SUDO is used only when you want to give some users privilege to run the command as root like a normal user will not be able to do the command "service network restart" but if you allow the user have sudo privileges, he will be able to do it.

Comment: `sudo` confers full root access, as you can use it to run arbitrary code, such as a shell.